# How to pre-render initial page in VueJS using Webpack?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, prerender

Is it possible to pre-render initial page of a VueJS app in Webpack as its done in preact-cli? 
https://github.com/developit/preact-cli

Possible option that I can think of is Vue SSR, but is there a plugin available which does this? I couldn't find any which works.

Answer (score 0):

[Nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org) supports static pre-rendering.

Comment: But I only want client side rendering. And only root route to get prerendered

Comment: @VinayBedre, maybe [`nuxt generate`](https://nuxtjs.org/guide#static-generated-pre-rendering-) then?

Comment: @YuriyN. The page says, When building your application, it will generate the HTML for every one of your routes and store it in a file. But what I want is a Vue app purely based on Client Side Rendering, to preload only '/' so that in generated index.html, the rendered (above the fold) HTML/CSS gets inlined